# R install_github() issue with remote_sha()

Tags: r, github, devtools

I have been working on a project that requires the development version of the CBPS package found here:

https://github.com/kosukeimai/CBPS

When I try to run:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("kosukeimai/CBPS", dependencies = TRUE)
```

The install_github() line gives me the following error:

`Error in class(xx) <- cl : attempt to set an attribute on NULL`

After doing some debugging, it seems that the remote_sha() line within the install_github() function. I've looked around for others with similar issues and haven't found anything.

Some session info:

```
- Session info------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
 os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2019-02-19
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of `devtools` are you using? Can you show more of the output from the `install_github` command. Or is the error the only line you get?

Comment: I am using devtools 2.0.1. The error line was the only line returned.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to get help by posting an issue to the devtools github repo: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues

Comment: Good thinking. I just made a post over there: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1994

Comment: Ended up using a work-around to by downloading the repo and installing locally

Comment: this should work `install_git("https://github.com/kosukeimai/CBPS.git", dependencies = TRUE)`.